# How to test image upload (stream) with supertest and jest?

Tags: javascript, streaming, jestjs, supertest, superagent

I have an image upload endpoint in my API that accepts `application/octet-stream` requests and handles these streams. I'd like to write test coverage for this endpoint but cannot figure out how to use supertest to stream an image.

Here's my code so far:

```
import request from 'supertest'

const testImage = `${__dirname}/../../../assets/test_image.jpg`

describe('Upload endpoint', () => {

  test('Successfully uploads jpg image', async () =>
    request(app)
      .post(`${ROOT_URL}${endpoints.add_image.route}`)
      .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${process.env.testUserJWT}`)
      .set('content-type', 'application/octet-stream')
      .pipe(fs.createReadStream(testImage))
      .on('finish', (something) => {
        console.log(something)
      }))

})
```

This code produces nothing, the `finish` event is never called, nothing is console logged, and this test suite actually passes as nothing is expected. I cannot chain a `.expect` onto this request, otherwise I get this runtime error:

> TypeError: (0 , _supertest2.default)(...).post(...).set(...).set(...).pipe(...).expect is not a function

How is such a thing accomplished?

Comment: To pipe data to a request you have to tell the readable stream to pipe to the request. e.g. `imageStream.pipe(req)`.

Comment: `async`/`await` only works with promises, not streams. You'll need to change the test function to use `(done)` and call `done()` in the pipe's `finish`/`close` event.

Comment: @popthestack If you write up a full working answer I'd be happy to give you the bounty.

Comment: @IsaacHinman, what is the request object here? If possible provide a minimal git repo and you should get the fix soon

Comment: @TarunLalwani Sorry for that, `request` is the `supertest` library as indicated in the question title.

Comment: Can you provide the upload method so I can test it and make sure it works fine?

Comment: @IsaacHinman, posted an answer, see if it helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work. To pipe data to a request you have to tell the readable stream to pipe to the request. The other way is for receiving data from the server. This also uses `done` instead of `async` as pipes do not work with async/await.

Also worth nothing is that by default the pipe will call `end` and then superagent will call `end`, resulting in an error about `end` being called twice. To solve this you have to tell the pipe call not to do that and then call end in the on end event of the stream.

```
import request from 'supertest'

const testImage = `${__dirname}/../../../assets/test_image.jpg`

describe('Upload endpoint', () => {

  test('Successfully uploads jpg image', (done) => {
      const req = request(app)
          .post(`${ROOT_URL}${endpoints.add_image.route}`)
          .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${process.env.testUserJWT}`)
          .set('content-type', 'application/octet-stream')

      const imgStream = fs.createReadStream(testImage);
      imgStream.on('end', () => req.end(done));
      imgStream.pipe(req, {end: false})
  })
})
```

Edited to add: this has worked for me with small files. If I try testing it with a large test_image.jpg the request times out.

Comment: To clarify, the third parameter of jest test() can be used to overwrite the default 5s timeout.

Answer (score 2):

I had to make assumptions about your upload method taking the body as input instead of multipart form-data. So below is an example where the raw body is passed for upload

```
const request = require('supertest');
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs')
const app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.raw({type: 'application/octet-stream'}))

app.post('/user', function(req, res) {
    res.status(200).json({ name: 'tobi' });
});

testImage = './package.json'

resp = request(app)
    .post('/user')

    resp.set('Authorization', `Bearer Test`).set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')

    resp.send(fs.readFileSync(testImage, 'utf-8'))
    resp.expect(200)
    .then(response => {
        console.log("response",response);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
```

If you use `multipart/form-data` then below code shows an example

```
const request = require('supertest');
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs')
const app = express();

app.post('/user', function(req, res) {
    // capture the encoded form data
    req.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(data.toString());
    });

    // send a response when finished reading
    // the encoded form data
    req.on('end', () => {
        res.status(200).json({ name: 'tobi' });
    });

});

testImage = './package.json'

resp = request(app)
    .post('/user')

    resp.set('Authorization', `Bearer Test`)
    resp.attach("file", testImage)
    resp.expect(200)
    .then(response => {
        console.log("response",response);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const testImage = `${__dirname}/../../../assets/test_image.jpg`

describe('Upload endpoint', () => {

  test('Successfully uploads jpg image', async () =>
    request(app)
      .post(`${ROOT_URL}${endpoints.add_image.route}`)
      .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${process.env.testUserJWT}`)
      .attach("name",testImage,{ contentType: 'application/octet-stream' })
      .expect(200)
      .then(response => {
          console.log("response",response);
      })
  );
});
```

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to use `expect` and `then` in conjunction. Anyways, when running your code (which is very similar to things I've already tried), I get the error that the header content-type is _not_ `application/octet-stream`. It seems the `attach` method rewrites headers.

Comment: yeah,i forgot remove content-type. i updated the answer

Comment: @IsaacHinman, I think this should work, can you please check and update?

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually want to use `fs.createReadStream(testImage)` to read that image into your request, since `fs.createWriteStream(testImage)` would be writing data into the file descriptor provided (in this case `testImage`). [Feel free to checkout Node Streams to see how they work in more detail.](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html)

I'm not quite sure where you're getting the `finish` event from for `supertest`, but you can see how to use the `.pipe()` method [here](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#-post-put-requests).

You might also want to consider using `supertest` [multipart attachments](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#multipart-requests), if that better suits your test.

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo on my part. Of course we're reading into the stream.